# Editing a EditText edits it below the textbox

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

When I edit this `EditText` view, it seems to add all the characters into a line below the view. I want it so that when the user edits the value, the value automatically shows up on the correct line.
[image]

Notice how there is vertical magenta line towards the left of the horizontal magenta line. This is the cursor of the `EditText`. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Here is the xml code for this specific `EditText`:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/distanceText"
     android:layout_width="123dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:ems="10"
     android:imeOptions="actionDone"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:text="0"
     android:textSize="24sp" />
```

The entire .xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/convertFromText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Convert From"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/convertFromSpinner"
                android:layout_width="297dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/selectBoardRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/selectBoardText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Transport Type"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/selectBoardSpinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/distanceRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/distanceText"
                android:layout_width="123dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="miles"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/hoursRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hours:"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/hoursText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/minutesRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="24sp"
                android:text="Minutes"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/minutesText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

There are two other `EditText`s in this .xml file, and both of them work how I want them to.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `android:ems`.

Comment: Can you share the rest of that view's XML?

Comment: just updated the question

Comment: Typical response: Mine looks just fine - https://i.imgur.com/9Qd4KS2.png

Which version of Android and what type of device?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 3.1.4, using a Nexus 5X API 23 running Android 6.0.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using TableLayout. Just use the constraint layout properties to align those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was to just delete the EditText and create a new one (through the drag-and-drop interface). Not too sure why that worked, but the xml file was pretty much the same.